# Issue with Web Application in NetBeans

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I have a web application code which uses jsp, servlet and ejb. I created those using NetBeans 6.9 and GlassFish 3.1. Now, whenever I update my code, sometimes in my browser I found the updates and some times I simply can't see the new updates. For example, after updating my code, I found updated applications on Google Chrome browser but in IE, it shows older applications even if deleted jsp or servlets also. Now, this thing happening for all of the browsers. Whenever, I am taking a new browser, I can see the updated application. Can anybody help me why this happening ? And how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just have to delete cookies named "localhost---http8080---" like that.